# Unable to connect mobile to laptop using"adb connect ip"error is "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)"

Tags: android, appium, adb, appium-android

adb connect iP

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061) while trying to connect

Connected device after running the above command

[image: Image for reference]

BTW I later realized I need to enter the dynamic port number every time which makes the process as tedious as earlier with just the IP it used to get connected not sure how I can be connected without entering the port number like earlier

Comment: I see no command.. Please tell what you do or wanna do in your post before mentioning errors and such.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide more details. How is the Andorid phone connected to the network, where do you got the used IP address from. Have you checked the Wifi router if it allows communication from laptop to the phone (Wifi routers some times block communication between Wifi devices).

Comment: It is over same wifi network

Comment: @Robert Please Check the post again

Comment: You know that you first have to enable the phone to accept the IP connection. The necessary commands have to be executed after each phone reboot. You have to do this via USB-ADB connection. Only afterwards you will be able to perform `adb connect`.

Comment: @Robert i've accepted the ip connection but can you expand on what commands to be executed after phone reboot

Answer (score 0):

Connect your mobile with your laptop via Cable then it will ask for permission to allow it and you'll be connected. Once it's connected then you're good to go next time without cable using the command.

Comment: still its the same followed everything but still i need to enter the dynamic port everytime to connect